# Logging user activity in a web browser using python

Tags: python, events

I want to log user web driver actions such as navigating through sites and clicking on buttons.

iv'e been using the python module Selenium for web automation and was looking to find a solution using the Selenium EventFiringWebDriver AbstractEventListener but I have only been able to log actions done from the script itself.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver, AbstractEventListener
from time import sleep
class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):
    def before_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        print("Before navigate to %s" % url)
    def after_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        print("After navigate to %s" % url)
    def before_click(self, element, driver):
        print("clicked on %s" %element)
def main():
    driver = Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\user1\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    ef_driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver, MyListener())
    ef_driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/")
    ef_driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/")

    sleep(20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you further explain your problem. Do you own the website and you are trying to track user events?

Comment: i want the script to run on a computer and while its running it logs all web driver events so if a driver is opened its logged, if a website is navigated to its logged, if a button is clicked its logged so i can use those logs and later then turn them into mini automations. for example I start the script and open my chrome web browser and then enter into youtube and play my favorite playlist then end the script , all of those actions are logged and can be re run by me .

Comment: For logging, you will only have access to your own script's actions. You won't be able to log other actions.

Comment: do you have any other module in mind

Comment: You described you want to log all actions of your web driver, a web driver must have actions coded into it to run. I am confused about the goal and why logging only driver actions is a limitation.

Comment: how does one get the actions done in the web browser from the web browser

Comment: Unless you own the website, you can only validate your own actions. The owner of the website can record actions done on their site by users by tracking redirects and clicks from the server. You don't have access to the server only your local actions.

Comment: lets say i want to create a script that opens youtube searches a video enters the first option and then likes it, i can do that with a selenium script but it would mean i have to write a script for every series of actions i wish to do in my driver, what i want to do is write a script which starts logging actions i do in the driver when its run and when its stopped it saves the logged activity and turns it into a python script, except for selenium for the final script how would you go around logging my actions in the driver ?